# How to get serial terminal software supporting high baudrate?

Tags: terminal, serial-port, embedded

I'm working on communicating embedded device via serial port for debug. The device supports only 1843200 bps for baud rate.

But, my usual terminal softwares (minicom, Teraterm) don't look like supporting such high baud rate as they are.

What I want to do using such terminal software is:

- sending command string interactively
- transporting file to the device

Thank you.

Comment: Did you check that your hardware and its driver support this baudrate? It is not a common value, but some UARTs can use it when set up correctly. However, the driver is involved, too.

Comment: *"1843200 **k**bps"* = 1.8 giga bits per second!!!

Comment: @thebusybee
Thank you for your advice. Yes, I have already installed the driver for Windows. Regarding Teraterm, such high baudrate doesn't seem to select such high baudrate from GUI. But, it's available if launched from command line with the parameters (e.g. teratermpro.exe /BAUD=1843200).

Comment: @sawdust Oops! Super high baudrate serial!

Comment: Would you mind to post your finding as an answer, please? This will help others seeking help on the same issue. You might want to read some of the [help] to learn how this site works.

Answer (score 1):

As I commented, I solved the problem myself and post it again.

Teraterm ... high baudrate can be set from CUI (command line), not GUI (926100, max).

> teratermpro.exe /BAUD=1843200 /C=1

PuTTy ... Using "plink.exe" works with options like below:

> plink.exe -serial \.\COM1 -sercfg 1843200,8,n,1,N

But, you could have to stop "plink" once by Ctrl-c and type like below:

> plink.exe -serial com1 -sercfg 1843200,8,n,1,N < [file path]

Regarding Linux, I didn't find the way. It could be that the proper driver should be installed.

@thebusybee Thank you for your kind advice!

Answer (score 0):

What baudrate that is supported by a certain UART device depends on hardware:

- How high the clock source for the UART clock go.
- What prescalers/divisors the UART hardware support when translating the clock source to it's own hardware peripheral clock.

Some general rule of thumb is that divisors should not give more than 3% inaccuracy from the requested baudrate. More than that and you risk spurious data corruption, framing errors and similar.

Therefore software might limit the number of supported baudrates, not to correct higher ones that will be wildly inaccurate anyway.

Needless to say your embedded device also needs good clock accuracy, so if you are clocking it from something like an internal RC oscillator while running UART at 1.8MHz, you are very likely doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In ttermpro you can manually set the desired baudrate even if it does not show up in the drop-down list. Just type it into the field.